# Time period as percentage of the business day

Tags: php

I need to calculate what percentage of the business day certain period of time is.

To get business day duration I use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    timeOpen,
    timeClose,
    TIMEDIFF(timeClose, timeOpen) AS hours
FROM businessHours
```

The results I get are in the following format: HH:MM, like 11:00 or 10:30.

I'm a bit confused how to calculate what percentage another time period, like 4 hrs is of the business day hours is when I have half-hour values, like 10:30. I do not have other minutes, i.e. either even or half-hour.

Other than that I think my math will be something like this:

```
(4 x 100) / 10.5
```

Do I need to use some sort of `str_replace` to convert time to integer?

Comment: Thanks for down-votes. Any tips?

Comment: Do you need to do it in PHP or MySQL?

Comment: Probably PHP because I have a different query retrieving the other time period. Plus it's looping through week days... Thanks.

Comment: I think this will do! Is it easier to do in MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: I added an answer with more detail. With the little I know, I think it's achievable in MySQL but it's hard to tell exactly how without more specifics, and what's better depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the hours to decimal in order to do arithmetic with them. In order to do this, you need to explode each hour by `:`, and add the first element to the second divided by 60.

After that you'll have numbers you can do math with:

```
<?php
$timestamp1 = "10:30";
$timeArray1 = explode(":", $timestamp1);
$timeInDecimal1 = $timeArray1[0] + $timeArray1[1]/60;
$timestamp2 = "4:00";
$timeArray2 = explode(":", $timestamp2);
$timeInDecimal2 = $timeArray2[0] + $timeArray2[1]/60;
var_dump($timeInDecimal2/$timeInDecimal1);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CQlLP)